# selected element in ng-options with array

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble with setting the default item selected in the drop down.
I have the following markup:

```
<select(ng-model="myModel" ng-options="item for item in ['zero','one','two']" )></select>
```

And I am getting the following result:

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="0">zero</option>
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why do I get this extra option and how can how can I have the correct option selected. The ng-model would have 0, 1 or 2.
Thank you.

Comment: you need to set `ng-model` to one of the `select` values

Answer (score 2):

You get the extra option because you haven't set the default selected value for the select box.
Working example:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.myModel = "one";
  
    $scope.values =  ['zero','one','two'];
    $scope.selectIndex = 2;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <select ng-model="myModel" ng-options="item for item in ['zero','one','two']"></select>
        <span>Selected value: {{myModel}}</span>
      <br/><br/>
      <select ng-model="selectIndex" ng-options="values.indexOf(item) as item for item in ['zero','one','two']">
          <option>Choose</option>
      </select>
        <span>Selected index: {{selectIndex}}</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I realized that myModel has '0', '1', '2' values rather than 0,1, 2. So based on your example I tried 

ng-options="parseInt(item) as item for item in ['zero','one','two']"

but this doesn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle? Can not understand what your problem is.